# couldn't do sudo apt-get -f install due to kde-config-telepathy-accounts

Tags: apt, package-management

When I'm trying update ubuntu packages using command `sudo apt-get -f install` I'm getting below error -

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 602 not upgraded.
751 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 825 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 274324 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: The problem is plainly stated in the error message: `dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1`. Congratulations, you have discovered a rare bug since both of these packages are in the Ubuntu repositories. Please file a bug report for this issue. As a workaround, you can use apt's --force flag, but be warned that some account information may be lost if you do.

Comment: hi user535733 - I have tried --force, still the same issue persists.

Comment: @karel - this would be a dupe if one of the packages were from a non-Ubuntu source. However, both are from the Ubuntu repos; I believe that makes this a bug. The package conflict is missing from both packages' control file. Bugs are still off-topic and the question should still be closed, of course.

Comment: ok. How can I close this question?